# How to run linux binary video drivers in a sandbox/isolated environment?

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver, sandbox, linux-device-driver

I don't trust any binary, but i have to use nvidia video card driver.

Since xorg/video drivers runs as root and needs to access my hardware, is it possible to block internet connection to these drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no.  A process running as root can simply override any limitations put on it.

Actually, running the xserver in a chrooted environment with some hacked up net libraries might work, but that's way beyond the scope of what I can type out on my phone right now.